# Pyhton: внедрение оплаты криптовалютой

Tags: python, bitcoin, blockchain

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь API для моих целей. Мне хочется, чтобы у каждого пользователя был свой адрес, на который он будет отправлять крипту для оплаты товара. Так я смогу увидеть, что клиент заплатил нужную сумму. Если клиенты будут кидать крипту на один адрес, то различить кто и какую сумму отправил будет трудно. Для этого я собираюсь использовать BIP32 или BIP44.

Какой API позволит мне это сделать? И ещё важный момент, есть ли у API какие-нибудь лимиты, например, на отправку транзакций или количество имеющихся дочерних адресов. Хотелось бы, чтобы их не было. Спасибо!